# build error with VS 2010 and FindRibbons

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build

I have VS 2010, 2012 and 2013. I got an existing project from svn so it has never been on my machine before. When I tried to compile, I got the following error

```
The "FindRibbons" task could not be loaded from the assembly            
'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks, 
Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.  Confirm that the   
<UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are   
available, and that the task contains a public class that implements   
Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
```

I found several posts mentionning to go to

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\OfficeTools

, open the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets
and replace all 10.0.0.0 with 12.0.0.0 which I did

but then got the following error

```
The "FindRibbons" task has been declared or used incorrectly, or failed during construction. Check the spelling of the task name and the assembly name.
```

Comment: Can you remove and re-add the reference from within Visual Studio?

Comment: Have u tried changing to 11.0.0.0?

Comment: Yes, I've also tried that. Didn't help. It looks like some Visual Studio update broke this "FindRibbons" task (wrong assembly version or reference - no idea). Try uninstalling all versions of Visual Studio, then installing them back in ascending order (2013 with Update4). Worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty likely to be a DLL Hell problem, you have the wrong version of Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks.dll installed in the GAC.  It is missing the [FindRibbons class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.tools.office.buildtasks.findribbons.aspx).

There is a half-decent explanation for that, an early preview edition of VS2012 deployed a version of this DLL that was missing the class.  Discussed in [this MSDN forums thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/848b773a-2933-4371-a98f-f4346c427aed/office-ribbons-wont-load-after-installing-visual-studio-11-developer-preview?forum=vssetup).  Proposes the same workaround you already tried, not a solution.  Otherwise a reminder to never install beta versions of Visual Studio on a machine you need to get your job done.

The issue is extra convoluted because the MSDN documentation says that the class is only available for VS2012 and up, not for VS2010.  And there has to be a `<bindingRedirect>` somewhere that forwards version 10.0.0.0 and 11.0.0.0 to 12.0.0.0 when you have VS2013 installed.  Not sure where, I can't find it on my machine.

Needless to say, this is about as bad as DLL Hell can get.  Two possible solutions:

- Visual Studio does no longer automatically upgrade project files.  But that's what you want to happen in this case, you'll want to use the VS2013 tool chain.  Edit the .csproj file with a text editor (Notepad will do) and change the `ToolsVersion` attribute to "12.0".
- Get the GAC fixed and get rid of the bad version of the DLL.  You'll need a proper version first, copy it off another machine that has a known-good copy of this DLL.  You can find it with Explorer, navigate to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks.  You probably have multiple subdirectories there, I only have one for VS2013.  The DLL in the 12.0 subdirectory is dated 8/7/2014 and is 102,688 bytes long.  You can use a decompiler like Reflector or ILSpy to double check that it contains the FindRibbons class.

A desperation move if none of this works out is to re-install everything.  Still important to get the original source of the corruption fixed, pretty hard to do if you indeed had an early version of VS2012 on that machine.  Running setup.exe /uninstall /force does tend to get rid of that.  Good luck with it, never a fun problem to solve.
 -

Answer (score -1):

Try opening the **csproj** file and look for `<ItemGroup>`, in there you should see a `<Reference Include="Findribbons">` including `<HintPath>`. You might want to see if it refers to the correct (or any) version of the library file you're referencing.

Especially with downloaded projects you will find that references are sometimes not set correctly (absolute paths).

Comment: there is no Include=FindRibbons in my vbproj file

Comment: Do you have a link to the project?