# Visual Studio 2017 Live Unit Testing Fails To Build Upon Start

Tags: visual-studio-2017

This is my first attempt at using the new *Live Unit Testing* feature in VS 2017.

When I click on `Test | Live Unit Testing | Start`, I see the following in the output window:

```
[13:55:37.376 Verbose] - Orchestrator - Request to start Live Unit Testing. (Source = MenuItem)
[13:55:37.376 Verbose] - Orchestrator - Handling request to start LiveUnitTesting.
[13:55:37.633 Verbose] - Orchestrator - Connected to LiveUnitTesting process
[13:55:37.653 Verbose] - BuildManager - Allow to send a single build event.
[13:55:37.653 Info] - Orchestrator - Live Unit Testing started.
[13:55:37.653 Verbose] - TestExplorerServiceClient - Updating client state from Disabled to Enabled
[13:55:37.653 Verbose] - StatusMargin - Received a SystemStatusChangedEvent: Started
[13:55:37.663 Verbose] - BuildManager - Building solution.
[13:55:37.664 Verbose] - BuildManager - Building project ExcelLibrary.Tests.
[13:55:37.666 Verbose] - RemoteOrchestrator - Received SubscriptionEvent for 'C:\VS\ExcelLibrary\ExcelLibrary.Tests\ConMetPartNumberUtilsTests.cs - C:\VS\ExcelLibrary\ExcelLibrary.Tests\ExcelLibrary.Tests.csproj' (Subscribe)
[13:55:37.669 Verbose] - Aggregator - Received subscription request for 'C:\VS\ExcelLibrary\ExcelLibrary.Tests\ConMetPartNumberUtilsTests.cs - C:\VS\ExcelLibrary\ExcelLibrary.Tests\ExcelLibrary.Tests.csproj'
[13:55:37.680 Verbose] - Aggregator - Adding 0 methods from 'C:\VS\ExcelLibrary\ExcelLibrary.Tests\ConMetPartNumberUtilsTests.cs - C:\VS\ExcelLibrary\ExcelLibrary.Tests\ExcelLibrary.Tests.csproj' to the coverage aggregation work list
[13:55:37.685 Verbose] - Aggregator - Starting coverage aggregation cycle - work list has 0 methods
[13:55:37.687 Verbose] - Aggregator - Finished coverage aggregation cycle - work list had 0 methods of which 0 methods were defined in 1 open files
[13:55:38.106 Verbose] - BuildManager - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets(176,9): error MSB4008: A conflicting assembly for the task assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks.dll" has been found at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks.dll".
[13:55:38.118 Verbose] - BuildManager - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets(176,9): error MSB4061: The "FindRibbons" task could not be instantiated from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks.dll". Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
[13:55:38.118 Verbose] - BuildManager - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets(176,9): error MSB4060: The "FindRibbons" task has been declared or used incorrectly, or failed during construction. Check the spelling of the task name and the assembly name.
[13:55:38.136 Info] - BuildManager - Build completed (failed).
[13:55:38.136 Verbose] - BuildManager - Interrupting build queue -> no new assemblies.
[13:55:38.136 Verbose] - BuildManager - Interrupting build queue -> no new assemblies.
```

Thus it seems the culprit is a conflicting assembly for `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks.dll`. However it's not clear why VS is reporting this error since there is only one such file in the indicated folder (no *BuildTasks.dll.bak* or similar) and no other instances of `devenv.exe` are running, and all add-ins are disabled. And I've tried killing all but essential processes and rebooting, etc.

Interestingly in Visual Studio 2017 Installer dialog, the installed enterprise SKU is labelled as `Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 (2)`. Perhaps this issue is correlated with the `(2)` suffice. Originally I installed the Professional, later installed the Enterprise, and finally uninstalled Professional.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The problem was mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/30777648/1954871

You can try to install Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks.dll in the GAC:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools\gacutil" /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks.dll"
```

Comment: This works but 1. You must to restart VS 2017 if started. 2. Paths may be different. Instead of `\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\` you may wanna use `\2017\Professional\MSBuild\` or `\2017\Community\MSBuild\`

Comment: This is a known bug in Visual Studio.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/177025/running-visual-studio-enterprise-2017-v1522-devenv.html

Comment: Thanks for the trick. This worked for me in VS 2017.